# how to download from a FTP over HTTP link?

Tags: ftp, download, http, https

I simply want to download this package listed on this link: https://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/NetBSD/ But I am not getting exactly what it is. FTP over HTTP? Thought I am able to see the files but I cannot download the folder. How should I download this, can anyone help me? Any help is really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is an http server on a machine whose *name* states that it is intended as an ftp server.

To connect via ftp the address would probably be ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/NetBSD/

Any given machine on the internet can have any number of servers operating over various different protocols, the server name gives an indication of intention or way of identifying the server, but does not mean that it exclusively supports one particular protocol.

You should be specific about what you want to download. That directory contains several versions of items and different install images. Downloading that directory would get you several hundred gigabytes of things you don't need. You might find it easier to download one of the install images which should include setup packages  that you are after.